# Display the full Month name from string representation of date stored in “Jan/10/2015” format IN SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find the month name in the result from the date given as Jan/10/2015 in SQL.

Comment: Add only one database in tag. Otherwise you will get downvotes. Also add sample data, query you have tried and desired output

Comment: in which database you want month name?... some sql based db have different methods

Answer (score 2):

You can try the DATENAME function in SQL

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, '2017/09/25');
```

which in this case will return September.

Comment: Which dbms is this answer for?

Comment: Microsoft  SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Date/time functions are notoriously databases dependent -- and you haven't specified the database.  That said, your value looks like a string and not a date/time value.

Although you should always store date/time values using appropriate types (which is NOT a string), it looks like you can use string manipulation to do what you want.  Most databases support `left()`, so:

```
select left(datecol, 3)
```

In those that don't, use `substr()` or `substring()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('Jan/10/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MONTH') as MonthName FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much i was missing the TO_CHAR(). thanks for the help!